# Designing a high-$Q$ RLC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, resonance, inductance

I would like to make a series RLC circuit which will serve as RF receiver. I would like very high frequency selectivity, i.e. narrow bandwidth, i.e. $\pm$200 Hz.

The sharpness of a resonance is described by $Q$ which itself is equal to

$$
Q = \frac{\omega_{0}L}{R} = \frac{1}{R \omega_0 C}
$$
but also
$$
Q = \frac{\text{Energy Stored}}{\text{Energy Dissipated}}
$$
but also
$$
Q = \frac{\omega_0}{B} 
$$
where $B$  is the bandwidth and $\omega_0$ is the resonance frequency.

I am confused which one to use for designing process. If I take the first formula, it looks simple at first - big $L$ small $R$ and that's all. However big inductors has also bigger resistance i.e my 1mH inductor has 50 Ohm resistance.

How should I design high selective RLC circuit which can be use as RF selector for example?

PS: I would apreciate any answer as well as resources recommendation :)

Comment: Why do you want such a narrow bandwidth?

Comment: You're missing an R in the numerator for your Q expression I believe; it should be $R/(\omega_0\,C)$. Aside from this, you've gotten your thoughts straight; you've rightly identified of the problems of lumped circuit technology. Also, as @Farcher says: that is a curiously narrow bandwidth; what's your application and that is your RF carrier frequency?

Comment: The long history of amateur radio suggests that you have an impossible task. 200Hz roofing filters are definitely not lumped RLC elements. You might consider asking for suggestions over on the Ham SE.

Comment: @Farcher, I want as narrow response as possible +/- 200 Hz was just an example.

Comment: @DannyS Please give a real number that you actually need to achieve in your design. If you randomly ask for an RLC circuit with a $Q$ of $10^{\text{five bajillion}}$, then nobody is going to bother answering.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance, I am just experimenting and learning. So I am looking for advices/guides where to start in design of good RLC receiver.

Comment: @DanielSank, well I just want to receive frequency I generated with my colpitts oscilator. I build my receiver as RLC in series with values L=1mH, C=2.1uF, and R=40 Ohm. So the resonant frequency is 3473 Hz which is ok but when I monitor voltage on the scope the response is not sharp, has wide band width and therefore will pick a lot of uwanted frequencuies, right? So my goal is to improve Q factore and narrow the bandwith. My current Q is $$ \frac{3437 \cdot 10^{-3}}{40} = 0.0868$$ which is dramaticaly low Q, I am looking for Q > 10. Any suggestion how to get there? :)

Comment: Yeah, get a lower resistance inductor. $50 \, \Omega$ is a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $$Q = \frac{\omega_0 L}{R}$$ is a good design formula.
Say we want $Q \geq 10$ and a receiver frequency of $3.5 \, \text{kHz}$.
Let's arbitrarily say we want the characteristic impedance of the tuned circuit to be $50 \, \Omega$.
The characteristic impedance is given by $$Z = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$
and the resonance frequency is
$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} \, ,$$
so
$$L = \frac{Z}{\omega_0} \qquad C = \frac{1}{\omega_0 Z}$$
with values
$$L = 2.2 \, \text{mH} \qquad C = 9 \times 10^{-7} \text{F} \, .$$

Now using the very first formula, we have
$$ R = \frac{\omega_0 L}{Q} = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} \frac{1}{Q} < \sqrt{\frac{2.2 \, \text{mH}}{0.9 \, \mu\text{F}}} \frac{1}{10} \approx 5 \, \Omega \, .$$

Can we find a $\sim 2.2\, \text{mH}$ inductor with resistance less than or equal to $5 \, \Omega$?
We surely can.
Try the usual online electronics suppliers such as [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/) and [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/).

Comment: For the lazy, [here's a suitable inductor](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/SRR0908-222YL/SRR0908-222YLCT-ND/2353005).

Comment: Thanks for very comprehensive answer. However I have couple of questions. First, where this equation $$ Z = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$ comes from? Second, similary, how did you get equations for L and C. Using only resonant frequency equation I got $$ L = \frac{1}{C \cdot \omega^{1/2}}$$

Comment: @DannyS For your first question, look up [characteristic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance). The Wiki article is for distributed transmission lines, but the same principles work for lumped resonators. For your second question, just try evaluating $Z/\omega_0$ and $1/\omega_0 Z$ using the first two fomulas in the answer. Also, if you like an answer on this site, upvote it, and when you think an answer is acceptable, accept it.

Comment: thank you very much. Two more questions, can you recommend a good book which covers this subject? Don't limit yourself to just one, it can be also books from related subjects. Second question, you proposed some inductor above, I have checked it quickly and it looks like it has several legs/pins, I am just curious why?

Comment: @DannyS Regarding books, I cannot help you, but I'm sure the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange can. Regarding the pins, please take a few minutes to click on the datasheet link in the Digi-Key link provided above, and take some time to read the datasheet yourself. I can answer questions if you still need help after reading the datasheet.

Comment: I did check datasheet and it looks like every pin adds extra inductance but it never says how much of it and in what configuration. I know that this is of-topic now but in the same time best place to answer this doubt. Do you understand this datasheet?

Comment: @DannyS Look at the wiring diagram at the bottom.

Comment: no way it doesn't say anything about how to connect it oO

Comment: @DannyS there's a wiring diagram on the bottom of the second page. It costs $1.27. Why not buy one and try it?

Comment: sure I will try it but I don't like such uninformative datasheet as this one is. Anyway, thank you very much Daniel for help :)